# Execute select combinations and prevent pytest from running all parameterise combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, pytest, fixtures

There are 3 users and 5 codes

```
@pytest.mark.fns
@pytest.mark.parametrize("USER, PWD", [(user1, user1pwd), (user2, user2pwd), (user3, user3pwd)])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("CODE", ['code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code 4', 'code 5'])

def fn1(CODE, USER, PWD):
    ...
    ...
    do something
    ...
    ...
```

Right now, if I run `pytest -m "fns"`, the function `fn1` will run 15 times with all CODE and USER, PWD combinations. However I only want it to run 5 times like the following:

```
fn1(code1, user1, user1pwd)
fn1(code2, user2, user2pwd)
fn1(code3, user3, user3pwd)
fn1(code4, user1, user1pwd)
fn1(code5, user2, user2pwd)
```

That is, code 1,2 and 3 be passed with user1,2 and 3 and then the remaining code 4 and 5 be passed with user1 and 2.

Edit1: The number of codes can vary from 1 to 1000s whereas there are only 3 users. And each code needs to be passed only once with only 1 user.

I went through fixtures but its too difficult for me to understand. Can someone explain me how I can accomplish this?

Comment: what about `parametrize("CODE", "USER, PWD", [(code1, user1, user1pwd), ...])` the same way you did with `parametrize("USER, PWD", [...])`?

Comment: Its because the number of codes can vary from 1 to 1000 whereas there are only 3 users

Comment: Is it important to use fixtures and parametrize, or is it fine to call `fn1` directly many times all under one test?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I simply need to run this pytest for all the codes with each code passed only once along with one user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import itertools

def fn1_parameters():
    for code, (user, pwd) in zip(
        ["code1", "code2", "code3", "code4", "code5"],
        itertools.cycle([
            ("user1", "user1pwd"),
            ("user2", "user2pwd"),
            ("user3", "user3pwd"),
        ])
    ):
        yield code, user, pwd
```

Then either:

```py
def test_fn1():
    for code, user, pwd in fn1_parameters():
        fn1(code, user, pwd)
```

or

```py
# Not sure if list() is needed
@pytest.mark.parametrize("code", "user", "pwd", list(fn1_parameters()))
def fn1(code, user, pwd):
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. You are a savior. Yield is deprecated though. I'll open an empty list and append to it. Thanks again

Comment: yield is deprecated?

Comment: "PytestCollectionWarning: yield tests were removed in pytest 4.0 - fn1_parameters will be ignored"

Comment: `fn1_parameters` isn't a test, we don't want pytest to see it as one anyway. Usually pytest only sees functions starting with `test_` as tests, do you have some other configuration?